# throwing null pointer exception when loading contacts using async task

Tags: android, android-asynctask

When i tried to load contacts using async task it is throwing exception, but it is not throwing any error when i moved the code to onCrate method.

Here is my logcat output

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:1764)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15356)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4928)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1457)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:723)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:583)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15356)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4928)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:315)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15356)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4928)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1457)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:723)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:583)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15356)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4928)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:315)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15356)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4928)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1457)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:723)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:583)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15356)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4928)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:315)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15356)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1858)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1110)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1283)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1008)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4222)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4793)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:808)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:575)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and the async task

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);

            if (c.getCount() > 0) {
                while (c.moveToNext()) {
                    x.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));
                }
            }
            c.close();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            if (mContactsRecyclerView != null) {
                mAdapter = new ContactsListAdapter(MainActivity.this, x);
                mContactsRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                mContactsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Recycler View is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Contacts Loading Finished",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Log.e("Sony", "finished loading");
        }
    }.execute();
```

Can anyone tell what is wring in this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the following line to `OnCreate()` method

```
 mContactsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(newLinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
```

You have not set `LinearLayoutManager` to `RecyclerView` in `Oncreate()`

something like this:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
mContactsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
//mContactsRecyclerView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter());
```

Comment: That's what i did moments ago and came back and saw this answer. thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

This error happens not because of `AsyncTask`. Look at your stacktrace carefully, you'll understand, that app crashes on startup. Take a look on the last line, it points to `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure`. `AOSP` is an open-source project, so you can take a look on the source code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.0_r1/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.java#RecyclerView.onMeasure%28int%2Cint%29), for example. If you analyze it, you'll understand, that app crashes because `mLayout` is `null`. `RecyclerView` should have layout manager before showing data (before providing any adapter with data), and the best way to set it is at the `onCreate` method where you initialize all your views.

At the `onCreate`

```
mContactsRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recView);
mContactsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

Layout manager should be set once, thus you can remove redundant layout manager setter from `onPostExecute`.

Comment: @sony you should learn how to read it, it will greatly help you to understand what is going wrong.